# XML files transformed to output.xml by xslt transform

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

artworks.xml file:

```
<artworks>
  <artwork>
    <title>Adoration of the Magi</title>
    <author>GHIRLANDAIO, Domenico</author>
    <date>1487</date>
    <technique>Tempera on wood, diameter: 171 cm</technique>
    <location>Galleria degli Uffizi, Florence</location>
    <form>painting</form>
    <type>religious</type>
  </artwork>
</artworks>
```

author.xml file :

```
<authors>
  <author>
    <name>AMADEO, Giovanni Antonio</name>
    <born-died>b. ca. 1447, Pavia, d. 1522, Milano</born-died>
    <nationality>Italian</nationality>
   <biography>Giovanni Antonio Amadeo was an Italian early Renaissance sculptor</biography>
  </author>
<authors>
```

output.xml file :

```
<authors>
   <author>
      <name>AMADEO, Giovanni Antonio</name>
      <born-died>b. ca. 1447, Pavia, d. 1522, Milano</born-died>
      <nationality>Italian</nationality>
      <biography>Giovanni Antonio Amadeo was an Italian early Renaissance sculptor</biography>
     <artworks form="architecture">
        <artwork date="1473">
           <title>Faهade of the church</title>
           <technique>Marble</technique>
           <location>Certosa, Pavia</location>
        </artwork>
     </artworks>
   </author>
</authors>
```

The artworks.xml artwork author is a foreign key, referencing the authors.xml author
entries.

I would like to merge these two XML documents and create a new XML file, in which the
following information should be stored for each author: name, born-died, nationality,
biography, and all artworks. The artworks are grouped by form and then sorted on date. For
each artwork, title, technique, and location are stored

it is challanging : )

Answer (score 2):

A complete solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="authors" select="document('author.xml')" />
    <xsl:variable name="artworks" select="/artworks/artwork" />
    <xsl:key name="byNameForm" match="artworks/artwork" 
                               use="concat(author, '|', form)" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <authors>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$authors/*/author" />
        </authors>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="author">
        <author>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$artworks[author=current()/name]" />
        </author>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="artworks/artwork" />
    <xsl:template match="artworks/artwork[generate-id()=
            generate-id(key('byNameForm', concat(author, '|', form))[1])]">
        <artworks form="{form}">
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="key('byNameForm', concat(author, '|', form))"
                mode="form">
                <xsl:sort select="date" data-type="number" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </artworks>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="artworks/artwork" mode="form">
        <artwork date="{date}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="title|technique|location" />
        </artwork>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<artworks>
    <artwork>
        <title>Adoration of the Magi</title>
        <author>GHIRLANDAIO, Domenico</author>
        <date>1486</date>
        <technique>Tempera on wood, diameter: 171 cm</technique>
        <location>Galleria degli Uffizi, Florence</location>
        <form>painting</form>
        <type>religious</type>
    </artwork>
    <artwork>
        <title>Something</title>
        <author>AMADEO, Giovanni Antonio</author>
        <date>1484</date>
        <technique>Marble</technique>
        <location>Mars</location>
        <form>sculpture</form>
        <type>religious</type>
    </artwork>
    <artwork>
        <title>Something2</title>
        <author>AMADEO, Giovanni Antonio</author>
        <date>1487</date>
        <technique>Glue</technique>
        <location>New York</location>
        <form>sculpture</form>
        <type>secular</type>
    </artwork>
    <artwork>
        <title>Something3</title>
        <author>AMADEO, Giovanni Antonio</author>
        <date>1482</date>
        <technique>Some tech</technique>
        <location>Mars</location>
        <form>paper</form>
        <type>religious</type>
    </artwork>
</artworks>
```

And:

```
<authors>
    <author>
        <name>AMADEO, Giovanni Antonio</name>
        <born-died>b. ca. 1447, Pavia, d. 1522, Milano</born-died>
        <nationality>Italian</nationality>
        <biography>Giovanni Antonio Amadeo was an Italian early
            Renaissance sculptor</biography>
    </author>
    <author>
        <name>GHIRLANDAIO, Domenico</name>
        <born-died>b. ca. 1447, Pavia, d. 1522, Venice</born-died>
        <nationality>Italian</nationality>
        <biography>N/A</biography>
    </author>
</authors>
```

Output:

```
<authors>
    <author>
        <name>AMADEO, Giovanni Antonio</name>
        <born-died>b. ca. 1447, Pavia, d. 1522, Milano</born-died>
        <nationality>Italian</nationality>
        <biography>Giovanni Antonio Amadeo was an Italian early
            Renaissance sculptor</biography>
        <artworks form="sculpture">
            <artwork date="1484">
                <title>Something</title>
                <technique>Marble</technique>
                <location>Mars</location>
            </artwork>
            <artwork date="1487">
                <title>Something2</title>
                <technique>Glue</technique>
                <location>New York</location>
            </artwork>
        </artworks>
        <artworks form="paper">
            <artwork date="1482">
                <title>Something3</title>
                <technique>Some tech</technique>
                <location>Mars</location>
            </artwork>
        </artworks>
    </author>
    <author>
        <name>GHIRLANDAIO, Domenico</name>
        <born-died>b. ca. 1447, Pavia, d. 1522, Venice</born-died>
        <nationality>Italian</nationality>
        <biography>N/A</biography>
        <artworks form="painting">
            <artwork date="1486">
                <title>Adoration of the Magi</title>
                <technique>Tempera on wood, diameter: 171 cm</technique>
                <location>Galleria degli Uffizi, Florence</location>
            </artwork>
        </artworks>
    </author>
</authors>
```

**Edit:** Updated to drive processing by author, so that even authors without any artworks will be included.

Comment: +1 Very good answer: traversing authors and grouping artworks by author+form. Some minors: if you are going to overwrite identity rule use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$authors/*"/>` instead of `<authors> <xsl:apply-templates select="$authors/*/author" /> </authors>` and if you are going to use push style you could do it all the way down like `select="$artworks[generate-id()=             generate-id(key('byNameForm', concat(current()/name, '|', form))[1])]"` or you could use a second key for authors (that will add an example of keys on external documents).

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick.  It demonstrates a number of useful XSLT techniques - extending the identity transform, Muenchian grouping, using `document()` to merge data from a secondary document, suppressing output of empty elements - which made it worth working out in full:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:variable name="authors"
                select="document('authors.xml')/authors/author"/>
  <xsl:variable name="artworks"
                select="/artworks/artwork"/>

  <!-- use Muenchian grouping to create a list of all distinct form values -->
  <xsl:key name="form-key"
           match="/artworks/artwork/form"
           use="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="forms"
                select="/artworks/artwork/form[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('form-key', .)[1])]"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <authors>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$authors"/>
    </authors>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="author">
    <xsl:variable name="artworks-for-author"
                  select="$artworks[author=current()/name]"/>
    <!-- only create an author element if it will contain at least one artwork -->
    <xsl:if test="$artworks-for-author">
      <author>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name|born-died|nationality|biography"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$forms">
          <!-- only create an artworks element if there's at least one artwork with this form -->
          <xsl:variable name="artworks-with-form"
                        select="$artworks-for-author[form=current()]"/>
          <xsl:if test="$artworks-with-form">
            <artworks form="{current()}">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$artworks-with-form">
                <xsl:sort select="date"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
            </artworks>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </author>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="artwork">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title|technique|location"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got as far as the merging part of your problem using the [document()](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcombxslt/) function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="authors">
        <authors>
            <xsl:for-each select="author">
                <author>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="name" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="born-died" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="nationality" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="biography" />
                    <xsl:variable name="name" select="name" />
                    <artworks>
                        <xsl:for-each select="document('artworks.xml')//artwork[author=$name]">
                        <artwork>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="title" />
                            <xsl:copy-of select="date" />
                            <xsl:copy-of select="technique" />
                            <xsl:copy-of select="location" />
                            <xsl:copy-of select="form" />
                            <xsl:copy-of select="type" />
                        </artwork>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </artworks>
                </author>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </authors>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I used [Intel's XSLT command line tool](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-soa-expressway-xslt-20-processor/) to do the transform. Here's the command line:

```
soaexslt2.exe merge.xsl authors.xml output.xml
```